# how to get current date and time in command line

Tags: mysql, automation, cmd

I am using mysqldump to backup mysql database. Now I just need to use the current date and time as file name for the generated sql file. How do I do that if my current code looks like this:

```
mysqldump -u root -p --add-drop-table --create-options --password= onstor >c:\sql.sql
```

I also found this code from this site, but I do not know how to incorporate it in my current code:

```
@echo off
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ('time /t') do (set mytime=%%a%%b)
echo %mydate%_%mytime%
```

Please help, thanks:)

Comment: Yey, I got 1 vote and 1 favorite, I hope I get good answers soon:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve your problem [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-to-get-current-datetime-on-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format-for-usi)

Comment: that was the source of the 2nd code above,

Comment: @Ieyasu Sawada if you observe carefully all the answers then you will get its answers. There is not only code which is present above.